# Получение и обработка данных в фоне при помощи RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava, rxjava2

Начал разбираться с **RxJava**. Информации очень много и пока сложно понять, что именно использовать. Нужна помощь, чтобы разобраться.

**Задача**: *Получить данные из трех разных источников, объединить, обработать каждый из полученных объектов и вернуть одним списком, когда все будет готово. Все данные одного типа.*

Сделать все надо в фоне. Потому что данных много, с каждого источника примерно по несколько тысяч объектов. Когда они обрабатываются (перебор всех элементов с внесением изменений), то интерфейс просто умирает на несколько секунд. Очень хотелось бы от этого уйти.

Сейчас пока делаю так. Для каждого источника по отдельности.

```
@GET("contacts.json")
Observable<List<Contact>> getSourceOne();

api.getSourceOne()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(contacts -> {
        // 1. Перебираю все элементы и вношу изменения.
        // 2. Сохраняю в общий список.
        // 3. Передаю общий список в MutableLiveData<List<Contact>> result;
        // который в свою очередь передает их куда нужно.
    }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

И в этой конструкции как минимум два минуса: 1) При получении данных с каждого из источников, в `result` заново передается весь накопленный объем данных. 2) Обработка полученных элементов происходит в основном потоке.

Как сделать по правильному?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
Single.zip(
        api.s1().flatMap(data -> {/** тут надо обработку делать **/})
        api.s2().flatMap(data -> {/** тут надо обработку делать **/})
        api.s3().flatMap(data -> {/** тут надо обработку делать **/}),
        data1, data2, data3 -> { 
                                    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>(data1);
                                    data.addAll(data2);
                                    data.addAll(data3);
                               }
       )
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(
            data-> { /** тут обработанная дата из 3 источников **/ },
            Throwable::printStackTrace
       )
```

Comment: Вроде разобрался как обработать данные - использую такую конструкцию `api.getSourceOne().flatMap(Observable::fromIterable).doOnNext(Contact::createClearPhone).toList(),`. Но не получается сложить все вместе. Здесь `data1, data2, data3` первые два элемента подсвечиваются красным.

Comment: Может где-то какой-то скобки не хватает? Или я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: Почему используется `Single.zip`, а не `Observable.merge` например?

Comment: @kulikovman, насколько я понял, у вас в итоге получилось) Single я использовал, т.к. он логичнее для всех однократных операций. Ваш вариант, на самом деле, даже лучше. Разве что можно добавить `toSingle()` после `toList()`.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге решил задачу вот такой конструкцией:

```
Observable.merge(api.getSourceOne(), api.getSourceTwo(), api.getSourceThree())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
        .doOnNext(Contact::createClearPhone).toList()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(contacts -> result.setValue(contacts),
                throwable -> {
                    connectionStatus.setValue(NO_CONNECTION);
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                });
```

Разобраться помог ответ выше, поэтому отмечу его как правильный.

Если видите в этом варианте какие-то ошибки или может быть знаете *как его можно улучшить*, то напишите пожалуйста в комментариях.